# Не могу разобраться с пагинацией aiogram_inline_paginations

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня не получается создать нормально пагинацию для `inline` кнопок iaogram.

Суть заключается в том, что в боте есть несколько категорий. При нажатии на категории всплывают `inline` кнопки из базы данных, разбитые по страницам, но когда я выбираю другую категорию, то первая страница всплывает по этой теме, а переход на следующую страницу отображает данные из предыдущей категории.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```py
@dp.message_handler(text = 'OSINT ')
async def CategoryOsint(msg: types.Message):


    kb = genButton('OSINT')
    Osintpaginator = Paginator(data=kb, size=5, dp=dp)
    status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='***', user_id=msg.from_user.id)

    if status['status']!='left':
        await msg.answer(text=f'Материал по категории {msg.text}', reply_markup=Osintpaginator())


    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=msg.from_user.id, text='Необходимо подписаться на канал', reply_markup=kb.keyBoard3)

    args,kwargs=Osintpaginator.paginator_handler()
    dp.callback_query_handler(*args, **kwargs)

@dp.message_handler(text = "ИБ ")
async def CategoryIB(msg: types.Message):

    kb = genButton('ИБ')
    IBpaginator = Paginator(data=kb, size=5, dp=dp)


    status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='***', user_id=msg.from_user.id)
    if status['status'] != 'left':
        message  = await msg.answer( text=f'Материал по категории {msg.text}',
                               reply_markup=IBpaginator())
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=msg.from_user.id, text='Необходимо подписаться на канал',
                               reply_markup=kb.keyBoard3)

    args, kwargs = IBpaginator.paginator_handler()
    dp.callback_query_handler(*args, **kwargs)
```